# How to save message to realm?

Tags: java, android, database, realm, chat

I am developing a chat android app and I want to save chat history and messages so that when user start app and user able to see a chat history and messages and implemented realm but it is not working as expected.

Below my User Model class

```
public class User extends RealmObject implements IChatUser {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Bitmap icon;

    public User(int id, String name, Bitmap icon) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return this.id.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return this.icon;
    }


    @Override
    public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    } 
}
```

Below MessengerActivity

Where I have implemented realm database

```
        Realm.init(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.beginTransaction();

        User userModel =  realm.createObject(User.class);
        userModel.setId(Integer.valueOf("Id"));
        userModel.setName("Name");
        //userModel.setIcon("icon");


        realm.commitTransaction();


        RealmResults <User> userModels = realm.where(User.class).findAll();

        String getId = userModels.getId();
        String getName = userModels.getName();
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working? I see you are reading results but not using results read (using `userModel` instead of `userModels`). Can it be you're simply not using result of db read?

Comment: @ror what is your suggestions then

Comment: @ror can you explain broadly what you  mean¨

Comment: realm.where(User.class).findAll(); returns a list, try to iterate through it, and call getters for entries in the list not for list object

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky can you give coding example

Comment: @SwedenEdgar
`RealmResults <User> userModels = realm.where(User.class).findAll();
for (User user : userModels) {
    String getId = user.getId();
    String getName = user.getName();
}`

Comment: @MaximBerezovsky thats it